# Archos 101 Tablet System.load() fails when loading ndk lib

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, archos

I have an app that has both java and NDK (C code). This app is running fine on the Motorola Xoom, but fails on the Archos 101 tablet.

Here is the offending code:

```
    static {
    try
    {
        System.loadLibrary("cube");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.d("scroll", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat dump on the error:

```
DEBUG/dalvikvm(10198): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.gorglucks.cubendk/lib/libcube.so 0x45497b18
INFO/dalvikvm(10198): Unable to dlopen(/data/data/com.gorglucks.cubendk/lib/libcube.so): Cannot load library: link_image[1995]: failed to link libcube.so
WARN/dalvikvm(10198): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown during Lcom/gorglucks/cubendk/Main;.<clinit>
WARN/dalvikvm(10198): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/gorglucks/cubendk/Main;)
DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(10198): Shutting down VM
WARN/dalvikvm(10198): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d8a8)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library cube not found
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     at com.gorglucks.cubendk.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:24)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10198):     ... 15 more
```

My C library libcube.so is in libs/armeabi/libcube.so and shows up in the eclipse Project explorer. I have verified this, by looking in CubeNDK.apk .

Also I tried to load the lib using:

```
System.load("/data/data/com.gorglucks.cubendk/lib/armeabi/libcube.so");
```

This failed as well.

Again, this works fine on the Motorola Xoom. In general, working with this Archos 101 has been very frustrating. The usb driver is not working for me on 64bit PCs, but will work on older 32bit PCs.

Thanks in advance
Jerry

Comment: Are you sure libcube isn't trying to load another library which isn't present in the directory?

Comment: I am pretty sure every thing is present, here are my includes: #include <jni.h>
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <GLES/glext.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
#include <android/asset_manager_jni.h>

Comment: LOCAL_MODULE := cube
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := cube.c DDSOpengl.c DDSReader.c screenGrab.c PVROpengl.c PVRReader.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -ldl -llog
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -landroid

Answer (score 0):

Through a process of elimination, and digging into the documentation android-ndk-r7/docs/STABLE-APIS.html, the asset manager is not available in API level 8 (Froyo).

This solves my link problem, but creates another issue:

How do you access files in the assets directory from the ndk without using the asset manager?

Comment: If you have another question then post it separately. Also, it would be helpful for `android-ndk-r7/docs/STABLE-APIS.html` to be a working hyperlink. Good luck with your question.